# How to make crontab execute every 2 hours between 10am and 10pm?

Tags: cron

I need my crontab to execute every 2 hours starting at 10am and the last one running at 10pm.

I currently have

```
0 */2 * * * /directory/job.sh
```

How do I block out the hours I don't want?

Thanks!

Comment: Would it be:    */120 8-22 * * *  so it's 2 hours after 8am, so 10pm. Then last one would be at 10pm?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[`0 10/2 * * * /directory/job.sh`](https://crontab.guru/#0_10/2_*_*_*) would do it.

[`0 10-22/2 * * * /directory/job.sh`](https://crontab.guru/#0_10-22/2_*_*_*) would do it and be more explicit.

[`0 10,12,14,16,18,20,22 * * * /directory/job.sh`](https://crontab.guru/#0_10,12,14,16,18,20,22_*_*_*) would do it, too.